# how i get navigation button click?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am work on an application in Titanium. I have a problem, I create a navigation based application. in this, how, I get navigation button is clicked or not. 
I create a Navigation and add the second window every time and work properly.
But, how i get navigation button is click or not?
if any idea than suggest me!
thanks in advance.

Comment: is that android application or an iphone application ? please share the code which you are using to create the navigation thanks

Comment: but, can use navigation in android also?

Comment: as by looking in there API doc you android does not have any navigationGroup.

Comment: your query is not estimated.Please make it more Clear.it looks like very Simple to fix.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add click listener for the button like this,

`urViewInstance.addEventListener("click", urHandlerFunction);`

Inside the handler function you can do your calculations.